# FetchedResultsController values are not overwriting custom NSManagedObject init values

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using a NSFetchedResultsController to get data from CoreData and load a table view with four sections. It works perfectly when the app is run for the first time, loading a plist into CoreData and then fetching records to configure cells in 4 sections of a table.

The problem occurs when I restart the app, init values from the class appear to overwrite the values that I thought/think were stored in core data. Values that are not initialized by the class are successfully loaded by the NSFetchedResultsController.

For example, there is a value, tableSection, to define table sections. When the table loads for the very first time, it has the four sections:

[image]

BUT, if I run the app again, there is only 1 tableSection value, 'My Records' (a default value intended for when the user first creates a record):

[image]

I'm not sure, but I figure this happens when I configure the cell...

```
func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let record = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Record ...}
```

It looks like when the custom class is initiated the init values are assigned and never overwritten by the values I thought would be in the fetchedResultsContainer. Anything not given a value in the custom class init, like the text and image, are assigned values from the fetchedResultsController:

```
    class Record: NSManagedObject
{
    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?)
    {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        let randomBit = String(arc4random_uniform(100))
        iD = NSDate().toIDTimeDateString() + "-" + randomBit + "OtR"

        believers = 0
        deviceTime = NSDate()
        doubters = 0
        eventTimeStarted = NSDate()
        eventTimeEnded = NSDate()
        featureImageIndex = 0
        coreLocationUsed = 0
        photoTaken = 0
        tableSection = "My Records"
        timeRecorded = deviceTime
        validationScore = 0
    }
}
```

How do I instantiate a 'Record' in a way that will overwrite the init values with the data from the fetchedResultsController? (if this is my problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set values for a `NSManagedObject` in the `init` method.  A `NSManagedObject` gets populated after the `init` is called.  If you need to override values then do so in the `awakeFromFetch` or `awakeFromInsert` methods.

I would strongly suggest reviewing the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/LifeofaManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH16-SW1) on what to override.

Comment: Oh yeah - You are discouraged from overriding initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext: and description. If description fires a fault during a debugging operation, the results may be unpredictable. You should typically not override the key-value coding methods such as valueForKey: and setValue:forKeyPath:. Gotit, thanks.